# Differentiating between a dashboard layout and other view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dashboard

There is probably no right answer for this, but I would like to get input on what the best practices are.

I have a rails application built already. In the app, there is a dashboard view and a regular view. In the application.html.erb I will include the header and the footer for both views, but what is the best practice to differentiate between the 2 views?

The two ways I've been thinking about are:

1. Include a variable (is_dashboard_view) and check it.
2. Change the URL's to have a common pattern, like /dashboard/...

I am leaning towards option 1 since it seems to be a less of a hassle. Are there any other options and what would be the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to create a new layout `dashboard.html.erb` similar to `application.html.erb`. In this new layout you can use only those assets that you want to load for dashboard view and You can use a specific layout like this ....

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout 'dashboard'
end
```

**For rails layout per action you can use a method to set the layout.**

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :resolve_layout

  # ...

  private

  def resolve_layout
    case action_name
    when "new", "create"
      "some_layout"
    when "index"
      "other_layout"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of scenario we create a new layout `other_view.html.erb` in `app>views>layouts` folder . Then the controller which need to use it you can render as:

```
class OtherController

  layout 'other_view' 
  // statements/methods 

end
```

If you not define the layout name on the controller then it'll use `application.html.erb` as default.

**OR**

You can check from `params[:controller]` which controller you're currently in.

Answer (score 0):

You can user different layout for different views.

OR

You can differentiate using controller name/ action name.

```
params[:controller]
params[:action]
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller file, add

```
  layout :choose_layout

  def choose_layout
    return 'dashboard_layout' if action_name == 'dashboard'
    'view_layout'
  end
```

where both layouts are in layouts/ folder. you can change 'if condition' according to your actions/controllers/params.